# How can I skip HBase rows that are missing specific column family?

Tags: filter, hbase, column-family

For example, a HBase table has columnFamilyA, columnFamilyB and columnFamilyC, for some rows, columnFamilyA does not have any column in it. I would like to scan the table and return only the rows that have at least one column in columnFamilyA.

What kind of filter should I use?  I checked SingleColumnValueFilter, but it seems to only work with specific column other than columnFamily. I need all rows where columnFamiliyA contains at least one column. Not just data in columnFamiliyA, but the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only data from columnFamiliyA you can use `addFamily` method on `Get` or `Scan` objects.

Comment: I need all rows where columnFamiliyA contains at least one column. Not just data in columnFamiliyA, but the entire row.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible using standard filters. You can change your schema to work better with the standard filters or implement a custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do scan of scan. First do scan for columFamilyA cols. Then get the rows of first scan.